# NativeScript Sidekick won't run since CLI 3.2.1 update doesn't work

Tags: nativescript

I opened NativeScript Sidekick on my Mac and it updated to the latest version 0.2.5.

It shows a dialog stating I need to update NativeScript CLI to 3.2.1 and the only option is to quit.

I went to Terminal and tried **tns update** but it won't update to 3.2.1 saying the platforms for 3.2.1 are not available. (I posted to the NativeScript forums and was told that is correct -- the platforms are at 3.2.0 while only the CLI is updated to 3.2.1.)

I also tried **tns update 3.2.1** which simply says 3.2.1 platforms are not available.

tns doctor says 3.2.1 update is available.

NativeScript CLI version is 3.2.0
npm version is 5.4.1
node version is 6.11.3

I've tried creating a new project and it gives me the same issues.

How can I update to NativeScript CLI 3.2.1 so that I can run NativeScript Sidekick?

Answer (score 0):

Solved over on https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/tns-update-3-2-1-not-working/2766/5

the command tns update will update your project, not CLI. If you want to update CLI do:

```
npm uninstall -g nativescript
npm clear cache
npm install -g nativescript
```

The command ths update  is currently not working, we’ll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using nvm to manage your NodeJS versions** you can try to set the default version to the one that has installed NativeScript CLI. For example if you have NativeScript CLI on NodeJS version 8.9.2, execute:

```
nvm alias default 8.9.2
```

To check the packages installed on your active NodeJS version, execute:

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```