# Nativescript Sidekick won't start after CLI update

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

I found some dupplicates but those were not working for me:
[NativeScript Sidekick won't run since CLI 3.2.1 update doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609321/nativescript-sidekick-wont-run-since-cli-3-2-1-update-doesnt-work)
https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/tns-update-3-2-1-not-working/2766/4

I am currently trying to start Nativescript Sidekick but it always prompts me to update the nativescript CLI using the command

> npm i -g nativescript@latest

This does not work.

I also tried to uninstall, clear cache and install again.
This also did not work.

Any suggestions?

Logs:

> Main
>
> [18-12-28 16:54:16.851] (Info) ab.actionsLogger.shell.appVersion -
>   {"name":"NativeScript Sidekick","version":"1.14.1-v.2018.11.23.3"}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:16.864] (Info) ab.analytics.shell.clientId -
>   2084238102.1530883066 [18-12-28 16:54:16.878] (Info) ab.appContext.shell.appContext - No value provided [18-12-28
>   16:54:16.879] (Info) ab.appContext.shell.projectType - No value
>   provided [18-12-28 16:54:16.913] (Info)
>   ab.appValidityWatcher.shell.isAppValid - No value provided [18-12-28
>   16:54:16.931] (Info) ab.autoUpdate.shell.updates -
>   {"eventName":"checking-for-update","message":"Checking for
>   updates..."} [18-12-28 16:54:16.950] (Info)
>   ab.buildDeploy.shell.buildConfigChanged -
>   {"platform":null,"buildType":"Cloud","buildConfig":"Debug","isClean":false,"useSharedCloud":false,"webpack":{"isWebpack":false,"env":{"uglify":true,"snapshot":true,"aot":{"debug":false,"release":true},"sourceMap":false}},"isHmr":false}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:16.954] (Info) ab.buildDeploy.shell.isWebpackSupported
>   - No value provided [18-12-28 16:54:16.957] (Info) ab.buildDeploy.shell.isWebpackRequired - No value provided [18-12-28
>   16:54:16.959] (Info) ab.buildDeploy.shell.isAOTSupported - No value
>   provided [18-12-28 16:54:16.960] (Info)
>   ab.buildDeploy.shell.isSourceMapsSupported - No value provided
>   [18-12-28 16:54:16.961] (Info)
>   ab.buildDeploy.shell.canChangeWebpackOption - true [18-12-28
>   16:54:16.962] (Info) ab.buildDeploy.shell.isHMRSupported - No value
>   provided [18-12-28 16:54:16.966] (Info)
>   ab.buildDeploy.shell.isSharedCloudFlagSupported - No value provided
>   [18-12-28 16:54:16.975] (Info) ab.certificateStore.shell.isSupported -
>   true [18-12-28 16:54:16.987] (Info)
>   ab.codeSigning.shell.codeSigningChanged - {"ios":{},"android":{}}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:16.991] (Info) ab.codeSigning.shell.csrStore - {}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:17.004] (Info) ab.createApp.shell.lastUsedAppDirectory
>   - {"appDirectory":"D:\Projects"} [18-12-28 16:54:17.025] (Info) ab.editor.shell.editorSettings - {"editorPath":"C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe","args":"{projectPath}"} [18-12-28
>   16:54:17.040] (Info) ab.kinveyAuth.shell.configData -
>   {"shouldConfigure":false} [18-12-28 16:54:17.118] (Info)
>   ab.privacy.shell.privacyConfig -
>   {"skipTracking":true,"privacyPolicyUrl":"https://www.progress.com/legal/privacy-policy","intercomPrivacyPolicyUrl":"https://www.intercom.com/terms-and-policies#privacy","forgetMeUrl":"https://app.onetrust.com/app/#/webform/7897e80a-b8a4-4797-883a-bdacfe1ab8e4","unsubscribeUrl":"https://forms.progress.com/emailoptin","partnersUrl":"https://www.progress.com/partners/partner-directory","privacyInfoShown":true,"emailsAccepted":false}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:17.121] (Info) ab.proxy.shell.proxySettings - {}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:17.144] (Info) ab.subscriptions.shell.usageInfo - No
>   value provided [18-12-28 16:54:17.146] (Info)
>   ab.subscriptions.shell.accountFeatures - [] [18-12-28 16:54:17.235]
>   (Info) ab.userAccounts.shell.userAccountList - [] [18-12-28
>   16:54:17.237] (Info) ab.userAccounts.shell.activeUserAccount - No
>   value provided [18-12-28 16:54:18.898] (Info)
>   ab.analytics.ui.setVersion - {"version":"1.14.1-v.2018.11.23.3"}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:18.901] (Info) ab.buildDeploy.ui.pendingRequests - No
>   value provided [18-12-28 16:54:18.964] (Info)
>   ab.vueService.ui.routeChanged -
>   {"path":"/recent-apps","query":{"back":true}} [18-12-28 16:54:19.068]
>   (Info) ab.connectedDevices.ui.devicesListChanged - {} [18-12-28
>   16:54:26.253] (Info) ab.autoUpdate.shell.updates -
>   {"eventName":"update-not-available","message":"No updates available."}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:32.087] (Info) ab.tnsDoctor.shell.checkLocalBuild -
>   {"iOS":{"canExecuteLocalBuild":false,"warnings":[]},"Android":{"canExecuteLocalBuild":true,"warnings":[]}}
>   [18-12-28 16:54:37.873] (Info) ab.tnsDoctor.shell.checkDependencies -
>   {"node":{"name":"NodeJS","version":"8.11.3","versionRange":">=8.0.0
>   <10.6.0 ||
>
> > =10.10.0","versionToInstall":"8.11.3","isMet":true,"isAutoFixSupported":false},"npm":{"name":"npm","version":"6.4.1","isMet":true,"isAutoFixSupported":false},"tns":{"name":"NativeScript
> >     CLI","version":null,"versionRange":">=5.0.1","versionToInstall":"latest","isMet":false,"isAutoFixSupported":true}}
>
> CONSOLE:
>
> ## ENV:  {"ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\ProgramData","ANDROID_AVD_HOME":"C:\Users\run_j\.android\avd","ANDROID_HOME":"C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk","ANDROID_SDK_ROOT":"C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk","APPDATA":"C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Roaming","ChocolateyInstall":"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey","ChocolateyLastPathUpdate":"Fri
>
> Nov  9 12:41:32
>   2018","CLASSPATH":".;","CommonProgramFiles":"C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files","CommonProgramFiles(x86)":"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files","CommonProgramW6432":"C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files","COMPUTERNAME":"LAPTOP-23SLBRUJ","ComSpec":"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe","DriverData":"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData","DXROOT":"D:\Programs\SandCastle\","FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING":"Internet
>   Explorer","FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING":"Default","FSHARPINSTALLDIR":"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\F#\10.1\Framework\v4.0\","GOOGLE_API_KEY":"AIzaSyAQfxPJiounkhOjODEO5ZieffeBv6yft2Q","GTK_BASEPATH":"C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\","HOMEDRIVE":"C:","HOMEPATH":"\Users\run_j","JAVA_HOME":"C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191","LOCALAPPDATA":"C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Local","LOGONSERVER":"\\LAPTOP-23SLBRUJ","NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS":"8","OneDrive":"C:\Users\run_j\OneDrive","OneDriveConsumer":"C:\Users\run_j\OneDrive","OS":"Windows_NT","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Programs\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\run_j\.dnx\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;\"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Programs\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\run_j\.dnx\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;\"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Programs\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\run_j\.dnx\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;\"C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\";C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Programs\NodeJS\;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\";C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Programs\NodeJS\;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;;C:\Android\android-sd;C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Roaming\npm","PATHEXT":".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC","PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE":"AMD64","PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER":"Intel64
>   Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3,
>   GenuineIntel","PROCESSOR_LEVEL":"6","PROCESSOR_REVISION":"5e03","ProgramData":"C:\ProgramData","ProgramFiles":"C:\Program
>   Files","ProgramFiles(x86)":"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)","ProgramW6432":"C:\Program
>   Files","PSModulePath":"C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\","PUBLIC":"C:\Users\Public","SESSIONNAME":"Console","SystemDrive":"C:","SystemRoot":"C:\WINDOWS","TEMP":"C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Local\Temp","TMP":"C:\Users\run_j\AppData\Local\Temp","USERDOMAIN":"LAPTOP-23SLBRUJ","USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE":"LAPTOP-23SLBRUJ","USERNAME":"Mennolp","USERPROFILE":"C:\Users\run_j","VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH":"C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\","VS140COMNTOOLS":"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\Tools\","windir":"C:\WINDOWS"}
>
> ## TIME: appReady: 77.854ms
>
> ## TIME: syncProxy: 1042.114ms
>
> ## TIME: apiShell: 87.933ms [2018-12-28T15:54:17.245Z]: Shell Ready - {"shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":310,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":false},{"type":"index","ready":false}],"shellReady":false,"allWindowsReady":false}}
>
> ## TIME: modulesLoad: 473.362ms [2018-12-28T15:54:18.460Z]: UI Receiving Ready -
>
> {"uiData":{"readyForReceiving":true,"readyForSending":false,"sendRequestsCache":7},"windowHref":"file:///C:/Users/run_j/AppData/Local/NativeScriptSidekick/app-1.14.1-v201811233/resources/app.asar/ui/splash-screen.html","shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":312,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":false},{"type":"index","ready":false}],"shellReady":false,"allWindowsReady":false}}
>   [2018-12-28T15:54:18.461Z]: Shell Window Ready -
>   {"windowType":"splash-screen","shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":312,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":true},{"type":"index","ready":false}],"shellReady":false,"allWindowsReady":false}}
>   [2018-12-28T15:54:18.461Z]: UI Receiving Ready -
>   {"uiData":{"readyForReceiving":true,"readyForSending":false,"sendRequestsCache":7},"windowHref":"file:///C:/Users/run_j/AppData/Local/NativeScriptSidekick/app-1.14.1-v201811233/resources/app.asar/ui/index.html","shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":312,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":true},{"type":"index","ready":false}],"shellReady":false,"allWindowsReady":false}}
>   [2018-12-28T15:54:18.461Z]: Shell Window Ready -
>   {"windowType":"index","shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":312,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":true},{"type":"index","ready":true}],"shellReady":true,"allWindowsReady":true}}
>   [2018-12-28T15:54:18.715Z]: UI Sending Ready -
>   {"uiData":{"readyForReceiving":true,"readyForSending":true,"sendRequestsCache":15},"windowHref":"file:///C:/Users/run_j/AppData/Local/NativeScriptSidekick/app-1.14.1-v201811233/resources/app.asar/ui/splash-screen.html","shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":0,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":true},{"type":"index","ready":true}],"shellReady":true,"allWindowsReady":true}}
>   [2018-12-28T15:54:18.895Z]: UI Sending Ready -
>   {"uiData":{"readyForReceiving":true,"readyForSending":true,"sendRequestsCache":85},"windowHref":"file:///C:/Users/run_j/AppData/Local/NativeScriptSidekick/app-1.14.1-v201811233/resources/app.asar/ui/index.html","shellData":{"lastModuleEvent":"componentsReady","moduleEventsCache":64,"sendRequestsCache":0,"windows":[{"type":"splash-screen","ready":true},{"type":"index","ready":true}],"shellReady":true,"allWindowsReady":true}}
>
> ## TIME: initWindows: 2918.208ms
>
> ## TIME: checkPrerequisites: 22657.786ms

Comment: Any logs which you can share. You can find the logs from Help -> Show Logs or from below path - C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NativeScriptSidekick\Logs

Comment: @Baskar Updated question with logs, couldn't find any other then the setup logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two versions of npm installed without me knowing. Had to uninstall one of them and reset my PATH variable to the correct location.

This fixed the issue!